# SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input client.login(token);

Tags: javascript, discord.js

Today i was trying to make a bot that sends welcome messages for my friend's server when i got this error and i dont know how to solve it, i tried multiple things in my code to fix it but it still does not work, i would appreciate if someone knows how to help me with this.

Error log:

```
C:\Users\LUCAS\Desktop\sachabot\index.js:34
client.login(token);


SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input
←[90m    at Object.compileFunction (node:vm:352:18)←[39m
←[90m    at wrapSafe (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1031:15)←[39m
←[90m    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1065:27)←[39m
←[90m    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10)←[39m
←[90m    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)←[39m
←[90m    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)←[39m
←[90m    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:79:12)←[39m
←[90m    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47←[39m
```

Code that im using:

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();

const config = require("./config.json");

client.on("ready", () => {
  console.log("im on!");

client.on("guildMemberAdd", async (member) => { 

  let guild = await client.guilds.cache.get("server id here");
  let channel = await client.channels.cache.get("welcome channel id here");
  let emoji = await member.guild.emojis.cache.find(emoji => emoji.name === "emogi");

  if (guild != member.guild) {
    return console.log("i dont recognize this server...");
   } else {

      let embed = await new Discord.MessageEmbed()
      .setColor("#7c2ae8")
      .setAuthor(member.user.tag, member.user.displayAvatarURL())
      .setTitle(`${emoji} welcome ${emoji}`)
      .setImage("https://tenor.com/view/dancing-baby-pacifier-shades-gif-5960764")
      .setDescription(`**${member.user}**, Welcome to the server **${guild.name}**! in this exact moment we have **${member.guild.memberCount} members**, be cool!`)
      .setThumbnail(member.user.displayAvatarURL({ dynamic: true, format: "png", size: 1024 }))
      .setFooter('User ID: ' + member.user.id)
      .setTimestamp();

    await channel.send(embed);
  }

});

client.login(token);
```

Answer (score 1):

Syntax error on line 7. Be more careful when posting question like this.

```js
client.on("ready", () => {
  console.log("im on!");
}) // this line is missing "})"
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to close your first callback. Adding another `});` after the first `});`should fix it